# phpMyAdmin relation twice in list?

Tags: mysql

Why is it that when I've a relation in MySQL/phpMyAdmin (PMA), PMA gives me the relation twice but in opposite order (ID - Name and Name - ID), what's the difference?

For better explanation, here's an image:
http://cloudho.st/i/ia10RaxA.png

I hope this isn't against regulations, it said I was not allowed to embed an image, but it might make my question more clearly with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that the upper are sorted by ID and the lower list by reference name, strictly for PMA view only.